# Dark matter, dark energy

Tags: dark-matter, dark-energy

As I understand dark matter and dark energy are quite theoretical . That modern theories require the existence of these phenomena. I read a lot of information about this. And I realized that scientists know more about what dark matter is not than what it is.
Can it turn out to be that dark matter and energy have very different features than expected? Or they are not real, just an illusion caused by gravitational interactions between short-lived particles of matter and antimatter. If you imagine it,how it will change our understanding of space, expansion or other things?

Comment: im just inderested "What if?", not saying that it is so)

Comment: I hope you get some intelligent answers, especially regarding your idea that the appearance of DM and DE is actually due to gravity of virtual particles in space.

Comment: It seems to me that this last question is rather opinion based. The rest of it seems speculative, debatably non-mainstream too.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos, don't you think these are probably the reflections of a rather young person, encountering these concepts of modern physics and thinking logically about them? And doesn't someone like that deserve better than to be told that their musings are "opinion based" and "non-mainstream"?

Comment: Of all the questions that get closed here, "young future physicists daring to speculate" are a definite sub-type. And it's just bad that people like that should be shut down for daring to speak up, especially when their ideas actually make sense!

Comment: Why are some people trying to close such very good question. People in stack exchange are trying to pinch out young budding physicists. Physics is all about questioning and arguing if someone doesn't want to argue it doesn't mean that it is to be closed. **StackExchange physics itself needs a serious moderation attention**. People who are closing out question needs to be removed. Feels ashamed now on this site, coz of such people;Always downvoting, closing and flagging.

Answer (score 1):

A quick comment about one part of this question - I might improve my answer later... Gravity from vacuum fluctuations of quantum fields (such as matter-antimatter pairs) is deeply connected to the dark energy question. That influence should be there according to theory, so it would be an excellent explanation of dark energy... except that also according to theory, it should be much much stronger than dark energy actually is. So one idea is that the vacuum energy has positive and negative parts that mostly cancel out, and the dark energy is the part left over.

I can't exactly think of anyone using vacuum fluctuations to explain dark matter, but someone probably tried the idea, as a type of quantum modification of gravity. I'll add a comment if I find such a theory.

Comment: Can u check this question of mine, its very similar to ur explanation above and i really liked ur comments @Mitchell Porter
http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/194133/gluons-and-dark-energy