# What is the dark energy & dark matter?

Tags: cosmology, universe, dark-matter, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

Can anyone explain to me simply what is the dark energy or what is the dark matter. I have been trying to understand it deeply. but I somehow failed.

Comment: Have you read the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy) [pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter)?

Comment: Too short to be an answer: Nobody knows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dark matter, dark energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161097/)